# What does section in .less file mean?

Tags: css, less

Example: I am not sure what 'section' means.

```
section.status-dropdown
{
   /* style would go here */
}
```

Comment: `section` is an html5 tag like `div` and you could have google'd that

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=section+html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Section` is not `LESS` specific and is an `HTML5` element.

[Here is link from html5dcoctor explaning a section](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/).

Here is an extract from the link:

> The section element represents a generic document or application
>   section…The section element is not a generic container element. When
>   an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

Answer (score 1):

`section` is an HTML5 tag.

Form the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section):

> The HTML Section Element (`<section>`) represents a generic section of a
>   document, i.e., a thematic grouping of content, typically with a
>   heading.

The syntax `section.status-dropdown` will apply the rule to all `<section>` elements with a class of `status-dropdown`.